# Delete last row of table unless its the only row with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have buttons that add and (supposedly) remove rows and elements in a table dynamically.

I cannot however get the last row in the table to delete unless it is the last remaining row.

My goal is there must be at least 1 (the first row with inputs) that cannot be deleted.

my HTML:

```
<TABLE id="tblTradesman">
<TR>
    <TH>Name:</TH>
    <TH>Arrive: (hh:mm)</TH>
    <TH>Leave: (hh:mm)</TH>
</TR>
<TR>
    <div id="rows">
        <TD><input type="text" id="txtTradesman<? $i ?>"></TD>
        <TD><input type="text" id="txtTimeArrive<? $i ?>"></TD>
        <TD><input type="text" id="txtTimeLeave<? $i ?>"></TD>
    </div>
</TR>
</TABLE>
<input id="btnAddTradesperson" type="button" value="Add" /><input id="btnDelTradesperson" type="button" value="Del" />
```

My Scripts:

```
$("#btnAddTradesperson").click(function () { 

        $("#tblTradesman").each(function () {

            var tds = '<tr>';
            jQuery.each($('tr:last td', this), function () {
                 tds += '<td>' + $(this).html() + '</td>';
            });

            tds += '</tr>';

            if ($('tbody', this).length > 0) {
                $('tbody', this).append(tds);
            } else {
                $(this).append(tds);
            }
        });
});

$("#btnDelTradesperson").click(function (){
    $("#tblTradesman").each(function(){
        if($('tbody', this).length > 1){
            $('tbody tr:last', this).remove();
        }else {
            alert("Must be at least 1 Trades person assigned to this job.")
        }
    });
});
```

[Link to FIDDLE demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yUfhL/399/)

I FIGURE IT OUT:

```
if($('tbody tr', this).length > 1)
```

Adding the 'tr' was key to it all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your html is invalid(`div` cannot be a child of `tr`) and need to use `thead` and `tbody` to separate the table header and body

```
<TABLE id="tblTradesman">
    <thead>
        <TR>
            <TH>Name:</TH>
            <TH>Arrive: (hh:mm)</TH>
            <TH>Leave: (hh:mm)</TH>
        </TR>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <TR>
            <TD><input type="text" id="txtTradesman<? $i ?>"/></TD>
            <TD><input type="text" id="txtTimeArrive<? $i ?>"/></TD>
            <TD><input type="text" id="txtTimeLeave<? $i ?>"/></TD>
        </TR>
    </tbody>
</TABLE>
<input id="btnAddTradesperson" type="button" value="Add" /><input id="btnDelTradesperson" type="button" value="Del" />
```

then

```
var $tbody = $("#tblTradesman tbody")
$("#btnDelTradesperson").click(function (){
    var $last = $tbody.find('tr:last');
    if($last.is(':first-child')){
        alert('last is the only one')
    }else {
        $last.remove()
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/XQ88Y/)

Comment: I was using an example i found on here today earlier and the only way i could get the table rows to actually appear was to have that DIV in exactly that place. I was in the process of editing the question with the answer when you posted your answer. Thanks anyway though.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is modified to make it work:

```
$("#btnAddTradesperson").click(function () { 

            $("#tblTradesman").each(function () {

                var tds = '<tr>';
                jQuery.each($('tr:last td', this), function () {
                     tds += '<td>' + $(this).html() + '</td>';
                });

                tds += '</tr>';

                if ($('tbody', this).length > 0) {
                    $('tbody', this).append(tds);
                } else {
                    $(this).append(tds);
                }
            });
    });

    $("#btnDelTradesperson").click(function (){
        $("#tblTradesman").each(function(){

            if($('tbody', this).length > 0 && $('tbody tr').length > 2){

                $('tbody tr:last', this).remove();
            }else {
                alert("Must be at least 1 Trades person assigned to this job.")
            }
        });
    });
```